# Is there any php standard that describes an order of placing public, protected and private methods and properties inside classes?

Tags: php, oop, refactoring

Basically, the title says it all. Is there any established standard that describes in what order to place `public`, `protected` and `private` methods and properties inside a class?

Comment: Quick tip - not really an answer: do you know the "Rearrange Code" function of php storm (and all other IntellyJ IDEs? I always find the way it arranges my code interesting and useful. It may also give you a hint at good/best practices.

Comment: @Barthy nice idea, thanks. Will look at it

Comment: How is this is duplicate of [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1760850/2936460)? That one is asking for general advice, while this one is specifically asking for a PHP coding standard. Voted to reopen.