# Tool to guard class order

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I look for free extension for Visual Studio 2012, which will guard me to write class in correct oreder:

1st const
2nd private fields
3rd constructors etc...

Comment: Personally, I would be concerned that you think such a tool is adding actual value - that seems a ridiculous thing to be obsessed about, especially if it makes the context / usage of fields less clear. The only time when "order" matters is in inter-related field-initializers, and then IMO the only "correct" thing to do is to move the code to .ctor or .cctor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *can* do this with [`StyleCop`](http://stylecop.codeplex.com), but I [would not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17554295/45914) call this the "correct" order. This is an *artificial* ordering of the elements of a class that is easily enforced by a machine, but is *not* a good scheme for readability and maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

[Regionerate](http://www.rauchy.net/regionerate/docs/2007/05/download.html) can handle your requirement. However, I'm not sure it still maintained.

However, my personal preference goes to [Codemaid](http://www.codemaid.net/). Its "spade" tool allow to manually but quickly reorder class' members. This allow to remove mess in a class, but with no military requirement to sort alphabetically.