# StyleCop conflicting rules: SA2104 and SA1202

Tags: c#, .net, code-organization, stylecop

The following two StyleCop rules collide!

> **SA1202 : All private methods must be placed after all public methods.**
>
> **SA1204 : All static private methods must be placed before all non-static private methods.**

```
class Foo
{
    public static void Bar() { ... }
    private static void Grep() { ... }
    public void Meep() { ... }
    private void Moop() { ... }
}
```

Given the class above, StyleCop will complain that a private method has been declared above the a public method

```
class Foo
{
    public static void Bar() { ... }
    public void Meep() { ... }
    private static void Grep() { ... }
    private void Moop() { ... }
}
```

Given the class above, StyleCop will complain that a static method has been declared beow an instance method.

If I wish to be completely anal with my code and ensure StyleCop always passes validation, what can I do, or is the only option simply to (God forbid) switch off one of these rules?

Comment: Also, answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/310967/1698557) already

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any conflict here. Is there a third rule you are not showing?

> SA1202 : All **private** methods must be placed after all **public** methods.

That first rule is only specifying the private/public ordering.

> SA1204 : All static **private** methods must be placed before all non-static **private** methods.

That second rule is only specifying the static/non-static ordering *within the private methods*.