# Primary constructors no longer compile in VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, c#-6.0

Until this very day, I could make use of primary constructors, such as:

```
public class Test(string text)
{
    private string mText = text;
}
```

To be able to do this, in the previous Visual Studio CTP, I had to add this to the csproj-file:

```
<LangVersion>Experimental</LangVersion>
```

Anyhow, this no longer works in the Visual Studio 2015 Preview (with or without `LangVersion`). Does anyone have any ideas about what could be going on?

Comment: They talk about removing it [here](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/568820)

Comment: Am I the only one that thought this feature was pointless? I never found the actual benefit for it.

Comment: It felt a little bit awkward, but I like the philosophy behind it!

Comment: That's a shame. But you can use primary constructors freely once you move to F#. Move to F#, csharpers, your new language features are already there ;)

Comment: @TyCobb, primary constructors are absolutely essential with dependency injection: you can use constructor injection (as opposed to property injection) without repeating the name (and type) of every dependency four times.

Comment: @TyCobb primary constructors would make creating immutable classes less painful, see [this proposal](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/543522) for what we could have had. With immutable objects you can share data easily across thread borders as they don't need to be syncronized. Writing such classes means writing much boilerplate code. Read-only properties introduced C#6 are a step in the right direction though.

Comment: Today, there is a proposal added here: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/27487fa/proposals/primary-constructors.md.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

> Does anyone have any ideas about what could be going on?

Yup - primary constructors have been removed from the plans for C# 6. They may well make an appearance in some form in a later version, but they're not in C# 6 any more.

See the ["Changes to the language feature set"](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/568820) post from the team for more details.

Comment: That's really sad! They seemed quite useful.

Comment: @PerLundberg: They're not in C# 7 either. I suspect the C# design team will revisit record types in C# 8, but that doesn't mean they'll definitely make it there.

Comment: Let's hope for the best. :) I saw them mentioned in some C# posting yes, and it looked like another interesting way to try and solve the "simple class" problem.