# Unable to use primary constructor parameter

Tags: c#-6.0

I am playing with new features of C# 6.0
I have the following line of code

```
public class Circle(int radius)
{
    public double circumference => 2 * 3.14 * radius;
}
```

Above code doesn't work and gives an error "The name radius doesn't exist in current context"

but when I use

```
public class Circle(int radius)
{
    int Radius = radius;
    public double circumference => 2 * 3.14 * Radius;
}
```

code just works fine.
Is this Some sort of bug from VS as its CTP or something is wrong with my code. as i believe i should be able to use parameter of primary constructor inside the constructor whithout setting it to some other variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Primary constructors no longer compile in VS2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26915789/primary-constructors-no-longer-compile-in-vs2015)

Answer (score 2):

*Well*, this may doesn't answer your question directly but **primary constructor has been withdrawn from C# 6.0.**

See: [Changes to the language feature set](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/568820) and this question: [Primary constructors no longer compile in VS2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26915789/primary-constructors-no-longer-compile-in-vs2015)

You are probably trying your code in Visual Studio 2014 CTP. You need to download and install new version of [Visual Studio 2015 Preview](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs.aspx). *(but first you have to un-install Visual Studio 2014 CTP)*

You may see the latest: [Languages features in C# 6 and VB 14](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MSDN magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn683793.aspx) on the new language features:

> By default, primary constructor parameters aren’t accessible outside of an initializer.

So you can't use them directly within any methods, which your calculated getter is.

Comment: but it you read "Expression-bodied members" it says "we can have members in our class that have an expression body".
In above case I should be able to use the parameter inside its scope which here seems is the entire Constructor function itself.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  The expression bodied members are just syntactic sugar, you still end up with a method and methods can't see the primary constructor parameters.  You're not inside of the constructor anymore, it's just the new syntax makes it feel like you are.