# How Does Resharper's 'Enabled C# 6.0 Features' Work in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper

I've been told that C# 6.0 is not going to be supported by Visual Studio 2012 and that to compile C# 6.0 code, I would need to upgrade to a newer version of Visual Studio.

However, when I paste in C# 6.0 code, Resharper asks me if I would like to enable C# 6.0 support.  If I allow it, I'm able to compile C# 6.0 code.

```
        List<string> customers = null;
        string Customer;

        int? length = customers?.Count; 
        Customer = customers?[0];
```

It seems to work, but can anyone explain how it's working?

If I go into the project's properties / Build / Advanced... the 'Language version' is set to 'default'.  And if I check the dropdown, I can only see up to C# 5.0.

Comment: As far as i remember it didnt work for assigning default value to auto property. Try that too maybe they fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32016203/1202807), it can work in VS 2012 if you have the 'Microsoft.Net.Compilers' NuGet package installed in your project.

Comment: I'm able to build C# 6.0 code in Visual Studio 2012 without installing any NuGet packages - but I don't understand how it's working?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you are using the ReSharper Build Engine (ReSharper -> Options -> Tools -> Build, see Build Engine)