# c# short(=>) operator overloading

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I'm successfully overloading operator like this:

```
public static Vector3D operator +(Vector3D v1, Vector3D v2){
    return new Vector3D(v1._x + v2._x, v1._y + v2._y, v1._z + v2._z);
}
```

I've read on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/overloadable-operators) that i could also do it like this:

```
public static Vector3D operator +(Vector3D v1, Vector3D v2) =>
    new Vector3D(v1._x + v2._x, v1._y + v2._y, v1._z + v2._z);
```

But in this case, under `=>` I got error saying "; expected". What am I missing?

Comment: It probably because of the C# version difference or Visual Studio version

Comment: As @Ian has mentioned, you're probably running a version of Visual Studio that's using an older version of C#.

Comment: thanks, what version of C# then it needs?

Comment: @PawełAudionysos what VS version do you use? The latest C# should do... but it really depends on whether you have it or not

Comment: I guess it needs to be C# 6.0, from visual studio 2015 on

Comment: I have 2012, I wanted to avoid getting new version as I have some custom setting I don't like to dig again... Is it possible to update C# version for VS 2012?

Comment: You can probably hack your .csproj file to use a newer msbuild/sdk, but you won't get much help from intellisense in Visual Studio so any syntax completion is going to fight you. I would suggest you stay away from the new syntax until you update to a newer visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the link you have posted the example:

```
public static Complex operator +(Complex c1, Complex c2) =>  
    new Complex(c1.real + c2.real, c1.imaginary + c2.imaginary);  

// Override ToString() to display a complex number   
// in the traditional format:  
public override string ToString() => $"{this.real} + {this.imaginary}";
```

strongly suggest that this feature can be applied from the Version of C# 6.0 since also the use of `$` as substitute for `String.Format` exist from the Version of C# 6.0 on and higher.

Try using Visual Studio 2015 to make it work. I did, it worked

> Is it possible to update C# version for VS 2012?

Yes, apparently it is. How to do it you will find in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32016203/5174469)