# Enable C# 6.0 in Visual Studio 2012 on an offline PC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, c#-6.0

I have read the answers at

[C# 6.0 Support in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28638547/c-sharp-6-0-support-in-visual-studio-2012)

however it's not clear how to get it done on an **offline PC**.

I have downloaded the latest stable version of the C# compiler available at

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/

but I'm clueless of what do I do with the dowloaded nuget package, best I could do was rename it to .zip and extract it but I got stuck again not know how do I reference that in `Visual Studio 2012`.

Also I have no idea how to upgrade `Nuget`to the latest version (as outlined in that answer) before I do the other steps?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use a computer that have internet access to retrieve the nuget package and copy it the the offline computer.

- Visit Nuget Site for the package you need .https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/
- Click the download package link on the page
- Use the nuget command-line interface to add the project to project file. For example: `nuget add -Source some/directory my.nupkg`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put your downloaded packages in a folder and use it as your package source.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/local-feeds

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the nuget package use the package manager console.

```
Install-Package SomePackage -Source C:\PathToThePackageDir\
```

Hope this helps.