# How to fix this "Invalid expression" term and syntax error in C#

Tags: c#

I have an error in the code below please the best solution.

I'm using visual studio 2012

Errors are as follows:

> Invalid expression term '.'
>
> Syntax error, ':' expected

Thanks

```
public event JobCreatedHandler OnJobCreated;

private void DocPrinter(SafePrinter printer, string documentName, string dataType, Stream stream, bool paused, int pagecount, string printerName)
{
    var di1 = new DOC_INFO_1
            {
                pDataType = dataType,
                pDocName = documentName,
            };

    var id = printer.StartDocPrinter(di1);

    if (paused)
    {
        NativeMethods.SetJob(printer.DangerousGetHandle(), id, 0, IntPtr.Zero, (int) JobControl.Pause);
    }

    // this line throws "Invalid expression term '.'" and "Syntax error"
    OnJobCreated?.Invoke(this, new JobCreatedEventArgs {Id = id, PrinterName = printerName}); 

    try
    {
        PagePrinter(printer, stream, pagecount);
    }
    finally
    {
        printer.EndDocPrinter();
    }
}
```

Comment: tried removing `?` from `OnJobCreated?` ?

Comment: The code you've posted works fine when I test it. There is nothing wrong with it. You need to provide the actual code that shows the error.

Comment: It still works fine. Please keep in mind that calling an event `On*` goes against the C# naming standard. The `On*` naming is for a method that raises the event, not the event itself.

Comment: "visual studio 2012"? This will not support the "?." syntax. Try `if (OnJobCreated != null) OnJobCreated(this, new JobCreatedEventArgs {Id = id, PrinterName = printerName});`. Or use a newer compiler

Comment: @KlausGütter - Write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "?." (null-conditional operator) syntax is available in C# 6 and higher. Visual Studio 2012 supports C# 5 only (at least out-of-the-box, see below).

You might replace the syntax by an if statement:

```
if (OnJobCreated != null) 
    OnJobCreated(this, new JobCreatedEventArgs {Id = id, PrinterName = printerName});
```

Or use a newer Visual Studio version.

Note: I never did it, but it seems to be possible to add C#6 support to VS2012: [C# 6.0 Support in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28638547/c-sharp-6-0-support-in-visual-studio-2012).

Comment: sorry I replied late, your code solution went perfectly

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a guess because you haven't provided enough code but I think you might be mixing up the `JobCreated` event and the `OnJobCreated` method. If you are using the usual convention for events then `OnJobCreated` should be a method, so having a `?.` after it makes no sense. In that `OnJobCreated` method you would raise the `JobCreated` event by doing `JobCreated?.Invoke`. Basically, you should have this:

```cs
public event EventHandler<JobCreatedEventArgs> JobCreated;

protected virtual void OnJobCreated(JobCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    JobCreated?.Invoke(this, e);
}
```

and then that offending line of code becomes this:

```cs
OnJobCreated(new JobCreatedEventArgs {Id = id, PrinterName = printerName});
```