# What is the meaning of this half class/half constructor c# syntax for reactiveui?

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I have been reading about ReactiveUI, and have reached a problem on the very first example! [On the project's website](http://reactiveui.net/), the following code is given:

```
public class SearchViewModel : ISearchViewModel
{
    public ReactiveList<SearchResults> SearchResults { get; set; }

    private string searchQuery;
    public string SearchQuery {
        get { return searchQuery; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref searchQuery, value); }   
    }

    public ReactiveCommand<List<SearchResults>> Search { get; set; }

    public ISearchService SearchService { get; set; }
}
```

And then,

```
public SearchViewModel(ISearchService searchService = null) : ReactiveObject, IRoutableViewHost
{
    SearchService = searchService ?? Locator.Current.GetService<ISearchService>();

    ... // example continues

}
```

However, I can't make any sense of the syntax used for the second part. It seems like it is half a constructor, and half a class definition.

What is it supposed to mean, exactly? I can't make a simple, equivalent example compile - is there some language/compiler extension at work?

Comment: An inheritance-chain at constructor? Seems indeed strange? Did you miss any generic parameters making those conditions to generic gonstraints?

Comment: Looks like a typo to me.  It seems like the example code is what they are trying to highlight, so you probably can just ignore that weird constructor signature.

Comment: Isn't that the new C# 6.0 default constructor syntax?

Comment: @Daniel nope - this feature was removed from C# 6.0. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26915809/1108916

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeeed an error/typo. The syntax is incorrect. I have just submitted a [PR fixing it](https://github.com/reactiveui/reactiveui.github.io/pull/3).

Comment: Yep typo, have merged the PR. Sorry about any confusion.