# Unity should I write first the Serialized Fields variables or the Public variables

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, syntax

I was wondering if in the order of a class should I write first the Serializedfileds that let me edit them in the editor, or the public variables (that even can be nonSerialized) but can be edited in the editor too.

I use to do it in this way:

-Public Vars
-Serialized vars
-Private Vars
-Public Methods
_Private Methods

It's that right?

Comment: It makes no difference to the compiled code. It's a matter of personal preference how you structure your written code.

Comment: I think, that you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a functional point of view, it doesn't matter. You can order them however you want, it will still work the same.

However, there are coding guidelines most developers adhere to.
[Jonathan Wright answered a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/310967/19359039) where he also linked the [c# coding guidelines](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1201.md) he cited from:

You would order them as follows:

- Fields
- Constructors
- [...]
- Properties
- [...]
- Methods

Within each of these groups order by access: (SA1202)

- public
- internal
- protected internal
- protected
- private

So while members with attributes like [SerializeField] are not explicitly listed, I would order them the same way you do, since the [SerializeField] attribute exposes the field to the Unity Editor and makes them accessible from outside.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter which order you choose, so long as you are consistent and have some sort of structure that you follow